# Quando é que "atual" passou a significar "do presente"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

[*Atual* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/atual) vem do latim *actualis*. Mas segundo o [*Latin Dictionary* de C. T. Lewis e C. Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dactualis), o latim *actualis* significava ‘ativo’ e ‘prático’. Segundo o Aulete, *atual* mantém este sentido, mas apenas como termo filosófico. Na língua portuguesa atual, *atual* significa ‘do momento presente, do tempo em que vivemos’. Não é difícil imaginar a evolução do significado: a  língua portuguesa atual é a língua portuguesa ativa... bem, ativa atualmente.  Mas encontramos ainda nos séculos XVII e XVIII *actual* usado com outros sentidos. Nalguns caso parece significar ‘real’, ‘verdadeiro’ (como *actual* em inglês), como por exemplo nesta [carta do Padre António Vieira (1626-92)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PRM2TugEG2oC&pg=PA221&dq=%22ocasi%C3%A3o%20de%20guerra%20actual%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeh8HowdDRAhVTnRQKHYewDqkQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=%22ocasi%C3%A3o%20de%20guerra%20actual%22&f=false) (ênfase minha):

> […] e que o dito capitão e soldados não sejam companhia criada de novo […] e que só esteja sujeita aos governadores e capitães-mores em ocasião de **guerra actual** ou delito que cometesse, e no mais estará à disposição do prelado maior da Religião que tiver a seu cargo as missões do sertão

Ou em [Pedro Taques de Almeida Paes Leme, *Nobiliarquia Paulistana*, cerca de 1770:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=uQ9KAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA50&dq=%22actual%20cavalharice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMuLOfzNDRAhVJSBQKHUvoB_QQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22actual%20cavalharice%22&f=false)

> […] não teve no seu tempo quem o igualasse no tratamento, porque de cavallos da melhor fama e bondade tinha muitos, e todos bons em **actual cavalharice**, e tao briosos que nem para beber agua sahiam para fóra sem antolhos e cabeções.

Então a pergunta é: quando é que surge no português o significado atual de *atual?* Esta transição também ocorreu no francês [(Larousse)](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/actuel/961?q=actuel#956) e espanhol [(Real Academia Española)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0cuhZiL); terá sido influência deles? Há registos do uso em português de *atual* no sentido latino original? Quais são os primeiros exemplos de *atual* usado no sentido moderno?

O [Centre Nationale de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/actuel) dá-nos mais informação sobre o cognato francês *acuel*, que poderá ser relevante para nós. O sentido moderno de *actuel* está atestado em 1750; curiosamente o sentido correspondente de *actuellement* está atestado no século XV. Anteriormente, *actuel* significava ‘que tem ação imediata’ (sXIV) e ‘ativo, eficaz’ e ‘real’ (sXVI).

Comment: Apenas para complementar a pergunta... O termo "actual" em inglês tende a significar "real", "o que é fato" ou "o que é verídico". É possível relacionar essas palavras nos 2 idiomas, bem como seus diferentes significados?

Answer (score 1):

O corpus do Português e o CIMP - Corpus têm duas entradas no século XIII de «actual» já com o sentido *atual* da palavra. (ênfase meu)

> ...en testemoyo de verdade que tal e
>   **actual** mulher, Maria Gonçaluiz, representada pelo procurador...

Acho que é claro no sentido do texto que a utilização é da que falas, por isso parece-me se será de uso bem antigo. Não consegui encontrar mais nenhum referência anterior nem mais nenhuma explicação além da que já referiste.

Parece ser um beco sem saída saber quando é que «actual» ficou com significado de *atual*, mas sabemos que no século XIII já era usada a palavra com esse significado, e nos séculos ulteriores também.

Comment: Eu acho que aquela citação está esquisita ("tal e actual"?); logo na página dos resultados do Corpus aparece qualquer coisa como *Manuel X e sua actual mulher*, que parece ter o sentido moderno. Mas pergunto-me se terá; acho que naquele tempo não havia divórcios; não será 'mulher de facto'. Eu dei uma olhada pelos séculos seguintes no Corpus, e *actual* parece ter o sentido de 'real', como *actual* no inglês. Encontrei também informação sobre *actuel* em francês, que vou incluir na pergunta.

Comment: @Jacinto da mesma forma que nao haviam divorcios também nao haviam casamentos. Ou se haviam [era mais comum a poligamia](http://historia-portugal.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/amantes-dos-reis-de-portugal.html).